# php extension mcrypt/curl must be loaded

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, apache

I was following a tutorial online about installing magento on ubuntu, but when I refresh the page at step 8/9/10(correct writable permissions on files) I get 2 errors: `php extension mcrypt must be loaded` and `php extension curl must be loaded`
I've found some answers online about how to fix it but I cant seem to find any answer that helps me. I'm running Ubuntu 13, apache2 and magento 1.9.0.1. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your PHP version you should install it using:

sudo apt-get install php5-curl
or
sudo apt-get install php-curl

and
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
or
sudo apt-get install php-curl

You then need to restart your webserver to make the new php modules load.

Comment: Now it just says mcrypt has to be loaded O.o. I restarted my webserver

Comment: @loko take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php You may need to edit your php.ini or created mcrypt.ini in /etc/php5/conf.d and add `extension=mcrypt.so`

Comment: @R.S I'm kind of new to this, but the extension=mcrypt.so is already in that file. And can you explain me about the php.ini thing?

Comment: @Loko Ubuntu (13.10 and 14.04) has an issue the `mcrypt` extension is not included automatically after installation. See [Magento not seeing mcrypt in LAMP](http://askubuntu.com/a/380293/18928) for the details and how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Ask Unbuntu - How do I install curl in php5?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5)

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl php5-mcrypt
```

You will need to restart the server afterwards:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Alternatively, if you are using php-fpm, you'll need to restart php5-fpm instead

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: Didn't do it for me. Mcrypt is still not loaded.

Comment: how to do in window wamp?

Comment: @gem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803265/how-to-install-php-extension-locally-on-wamp

Answer (score 0):

In **Ubuntu 16.04** default **PHP version is 7.0**, if you want to use different version then you need to install PHP package according to PHP version:

First of all Install CURL using this command:-

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

After that using these commands according to your PHP versions:-

```
1-> PHP 7.0: sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl    
2-> PHP 7.1: sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl    
3-> PHP 7.2: sudo apt-get install php7.2-curl    
4-> PHP 5.5: sudo apt-get install php5.5-curl
5-> PHP 5.6: sudo apt-get install php5.6-curl
```